# java - How to - Running total that is not in main function

Tags: java, cumulative-sum

I need to keep a running total but it has to be in my calc class, not main. My program does what I need except for a running total in calc. For the life of me, I can't figure it out. How would I go about setting up a way for keeping a running total that is not in my main function?

```
public class CalculatorImpl implements CalculatorInterface {

    private int total = 0;





    @Override
    public void reset() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        total = 0;

    }

    @Override
    public double plus(int a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        total = total + a;

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public double minus(int a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        total = total - a;

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public double star(int a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        total = total * a;

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public double slash(int a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        total = total / a;


        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public double equal() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return total;
    }


}
```

this is main program

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random(1000);

        CalculatorInterface calc = new CalculatorImpl();

        System.out.println("Answer 1: " + calc.equal()); // Print the initial
                                                        // value stored in
                                                        //calc should return 0

        // Test calc class 
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            // Get a random integer to select one of the four methods
            int r = random.nextInt(4);
            // Test statement for what it is selecting
            // System.out.println( "Int: " + r );
            switch (r) {
            case 0:
                calc.plus(random.nextInt(10));
                break;
            case 1:
                calc.minus(random.nextInt(10));
                break;
            case 2:
                calc.slash(random.nextInt(10));
                break;
            case 3:
                calc.star(random.nextInt(10));
                break;
            default:

            }

        }

        // Should return -218.0
        System.out.println("Answer 2: " + calc.equal());

        // Reset/clear
        calc.reset();

        // Should now have 0 in the calc, print 0
        System.out.println("Answer 3: " + calc.equal());

        // Simple example
        calc.plus(2);
        calc.minus(1);
        calc.star(5);
        calc.slash(10);

        // Should now have 0.5 in the calc, print 0.5
        System.out.println("Answer 4: " + calc.equal());

    }

}
```

here is the other class

```
public interface CalculatorInterface {

    public void reset();

    public double plus( int a );

    public double minus( int a );

    public double star( int a );

    public double slash( int a );

    public double equal();



}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? The field `total` is a running total that is stored on an instance of a `Calc` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total is an `int` and can therefore not hold the value `0.5`. Declare it as `double`.

Comment: I assume so? I have to keep a running total in my calc class that coincides with my main function. 4 calculations occur. When the reset function is called in main on the third, the total goes back to 0 as it then equals 0. But I need it to do one more set of calculations for the 4th, but it stays at 0 and doesn't have the total.

Comment: It might help if you posted your main function also

Comment: Okay, I've added all other aspects that could hopefully help answer my question. I know it's a weird program but regardless, I have everything right up until I need to get .5 as my answer for the 4th time.

Comment: Wow! I thought I was possibly making it harder than it was and of course, I totally overlooked someting so simple and small. Thank you!